# mkdir() says theres no such directory and fails?

Tags: php, upload, mkdir

Im likely doing something very simply wrong, but when I try to make a directory (using a variable of an insert just performed as the last folder name), I get the error:

> Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: No such file or directory in /home/blah/blah

with the code:

```
if (!is_dir("images/listing-images/rent/'.$insertID.")) {
        //make new directory with unique id
   mkdir("images/listing-images/rent/'.$insertID."); 
}
```

of course the directory doesn't exist.. I'm trying to make it now? confused!

Comment: Please explain what `"images/listing-images/rent/'.$insertID."` string means

Comment: Is the parent directory of the now-to-be-created-directory there?

Comment: Dont be confused. I think directory in which you want to create a directory doesnt exist.

Comment: .. so i forgot to make the /rent directory first. think I've been working too long! thanks everyone

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have an error in your string:

```
mkdir("images/listing-images/rent/'.$insertID.");
```

should be:

```
mkdir("images/listing-images/rent/$insertID");
```

Comment: I'm sure his error caused not by that, but by lacking of the `images/listing-images/rent`

Comment: So what's your final answer? There is no **syntax** error in the code. The string is syntactically correct (though pointless). As you said - this should be a comment :-)

Comment: If you'd like I can change the word `syntax` if you think that would make the answer more accurate

Comment: your change proposed in "should be" **cannot** change the behaviour - the code would throw the same error

Comment: ill accept this as an answer, for helping me eliminate pointless code, although comments to my question solved my actual problem :)

Answer (score 138):

It happens because you don't have `images/listing-images/rent` path existing in your filesystem.

If you want to create the whole path - just pass the 3rd argument as a `true`:

```
mkdir('images/listing-images/rent/'.$insertID, 0777, true);
```

There is also a chance you're in a wrong directory currently. If this is the case - you need to change the current dir with `chdir()` or specify the full path.

Comment: same for the above one.. only 1 sec faster

Comment: This should the correct answer since there is no syntax error in the code for which the "correct" answer has been marked as correct.

Answer (score 15):

Assuming you're using PHP > 5.0.0, try `mkdir("path", 0777, true);` to enable creating directories recursively (see here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php).

Comment: The only one that explained with relation to rules of PHP 5.0

Answer (score 2):

```
$path = 'd:\path\to\my\file';
mkdir($path, null, true);
```

This is copied from the php manual. The last argument "true" allows the creation of subfolders

Answer (score 0):

- recursive Allows the creation of nested directories specified in the
  path name.
- but did not work for me!!  for that here is what i came up with!!
- and it work very perfect!!

> $upPath = "../uploads/RS/2014/BOI/002";  // full path
>   $tags = explode('/' ,$upPath);            // explode the full path
>   $mkDir = "";
>
> ```
> foreach($tags as $folder) {          
>     $mkDir = $mkDir . $folder ."/";   // make one directory join one other for the nest directory to make
>     echo '"'.$mkDir.'"<br/>';         // this will show the directory created each time
>     if(!is_dir($mkDir)) {             // check if directory exist or not
>       mkdir($mkDir, 0777);            // if not exist then make the directory
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

in my case $insertID was generated from some data as string by concatinating

```
$insertID=$year.$otherId;
```

I simple rewrote code like this and error disappeared:

```
$insertID=(int)($year.$otherId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the real error was that he forgot an extra apex.

This:

```
mkdir("images/listing-images/rent/'.$insertID.");
```

Inside:

```
/'.$insertID."
```

Correct Version:

```
/".$insertID
```

Extended Correct Version:

```
mkdir("images/listing-images/rent/".$insertID);
```

Answer (score -2):

You shouldn't use is_dir() to check if something exists, you want file_exists() as well. Try:

```
if (file_exists("images/listing-images/rent/$insertID") {
    mkdir("images/listing-images/rent/$insertID.");
}
```

Have taken the '. out since it looks like a syntax error, but you might have a legitimate reason to keep it in.

If the mkdir still fails, it could be that images/listing-images/rent doesn't exist, you'll have to create that separately if so.

Comment: "You shouldn't use is_dir()" --- any clarification for that?

Comment: Actually disregard the first part, just checked the is_dir docs and it checks for existance as well, so it'll just be that the parent dir doesn't exist.

Comment: Should though be aware that [is_dir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php) caches results.  See note in page at php.net.