# PHP is_dir defective

Tags: php

Strange behaviour, exentially:
(the name of the folder depends on the date - the purpose is a hit counter of the website, broken down by day)

```
if (!is_dir($folder)) { // first access in the day
   mkdir($folder);
}
```

Well: on the server in internet all works well.
But when i try in local, with the server simulator of Easy PHP, happens that:

(a) The first time, no problem. The folder doesn't exists and it is created.

(b) subsequently, for example to a page refresh, the program flow again goes in the IF (!!!) generating the error (at line of mkdir) of kind: "Warning: mkdir(): No such file or directory in [...]".

All parent part of the directory $folder exists.

Thanks

.

Comment: It is unclear how `$folder` is created, for debug you should print the value of `$folder` each time the script comes to this place. Because if  `$folder` holds invalid stuff `!is_dir()` will return `true` but `mkdir()` can not make a folder from it. And do a mkdir() like  this `mkdir('path/to/folder',0777, true);` Read more here http://stackoverflow.com/a/15012257/4916265

Answer (score 0):

Try using a recursive directory creation function:

```
function mkdir_r($dirName, $rights = 0777)
    {
        $dirs = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR , $dirName);
        $dir = '';
        if (strpos($dirs[count($dirs) - 1], '.')) {
            array_pop($dirs);
        }
        foreach ($dirs as $part) {
            $dir .= $part . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ;
            if (!is_dir($dir) && strlen($dir) > 0) {
                mkdir($dir, $rights);
            }
        }
    }
```

This way all directories up to the directry you wanted to create are created if they don't exist.

mkdir doesn't work recursively unfortunately.

Comment: `mkdir` works recursively if you set the third parameter to `true`.

Comment: I ran into the same issue as this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php#68207  with IIS and php 5.6 so that's why i'm using this. The recursive function should work, but doesn't always.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone faces the issue; Use the native `clearstatcache()` function after you delete the file.

I'm quoting the interesting part of the original documentation

> You should also note that PHP doesn't cache information about non-existent files. So, if you call file_exists() on a file that doesn't exist, it will return false until you create the file. If you create the file, it will return true even if you then delete the file. However unlink() clears the cache automatically.

For further information here is the documentation page: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php